# How to copy the dll's using cmake?

Tags: cmake

I have to copy dll's to a folder while building my solution. The structure of cmake as follows:

```
    D:/src/cmakeLists.txt
    D:/target/runtime/bin
    D:/repos/stable/compiler/xyz.dll
```

So, i want to copy xyz.dll to "D:/target/runtime/bin" . I did as follows in cmake:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET performance POST_BUILD        
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different  
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/xyz.dll"  
    $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:performance>)
```

But it did not copied any dll. So, suggest me how do i achieve it. I am not much familiar with cmake .So, please suggest.

Comment: Leave the dll where it is and modify linking in the other project. Use `find_library` there.

Comment: try running `make VERBOSE=1` and look for the line `copy_if_different...`. Does it copy to where you are expecting? Also be aware that it will not copy if your target `performance`is up to date.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: Is the performance target build?

Answer (score 1):

I use the [configure_file()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/configure_file.html) command for that purpose. It copies the file during the cmake generate step.

Try something like

```
configure_file("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/xyz.dll" $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:performance> COPYONLY)
```

Comment: @swdon I forgot the $ in front of the <TARGET_FILE_DIR:performance>. Can you try this again.

Comment: I actually did pretty much what the question has (I used `copy` instead of `copy_if_different` and it actually worked. Thanks for trying to help anyway after three years :)